# How to receive custom message from a device in embedded system (Windows CE 6.0) using C#?

Tags: c#, embedded, windows-ce

I have a device with a fingerprint sensor attached to it. The device is running windows CE 6.0. I am currently using C# to develop an application for the device.

My question is:

I use pInvoke to initialize communication with the sensor. However, I am still confused on how can I configure my application to realize whenever the sensor is touched. In other word, how can I capture an event triggered by my sensor in my application.

Any advice is much appreciated, thanks.

**Update (trying to automatically tell my form what to do when I click the close window button)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    internalMessageWindow msgReceived;

public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.msgReceived = new internalMessageWindow(this);
    }

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        msgReceived.MsgEvntArg += new EventHandler<MessageGetEvent>(messageWindow_MsgEvntArg);
    }

     void messageWindow_MsgEvntArg(object sender, MessageGetEvent e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.message.ToString());
    }
}

public class MessageGetEvent : EventArgs
{
    private Message _message;

    public MessageGetEvent(Message msg)
    {
        _message = msg;
    }

    public Message message
    {
        get { return _message; }
    }
}

public class internalMessageWindow : MessageWindow
{
        public const int WM_CLOSE = 0x0010; 

    Form referedForm;

    public event EventHandler<MessageGetEvent> MsgEvntArg;

    public internalMessageWindow(Form referedForm)
    {
        this.referedForm = referedForm;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
    {
        if (MsgEvntArg != null)
            MsgEvntArg(this, new MessageGetEvent(msg));


    //switch (msg.Msg)
        //{
        //    // If message is of interest, invoke the method on the form that
        //    // functions as a callback to perform actions in response to the message.
        //    case WM_CLOSE:
        //        if (MsgEvntArg != null)
        //        MsgEvntArg(this, new MessageGetEvent(msg));
        //        
        //        break;
        //}

        base.WndProc(ref msg);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a bit more information about the sensor and how it's connected to your board/processor. It may require a driver (if it's connected via USB, for example) or you may need to understand which interface and driver you should use to exchange information. If it's UART windows CE provides standard APIs, if it's another bus (I2C, SPI etc.) you may need to discover how to interface with the bus driver (some companies provide application libraries to do that).

Comment: Okay, apparently I found out that I just need to open and communicate with the device using createfile and deviceiocontrol. Whenever I touch the sensor, it is supposed to return a window message of 0x0412, similarly to when i click close window which would generate a message of 0x0010.

I know that I need to override the WndProc function in order to tell my application what to do if it receives a window message. But I can't seem to sync the WndProc function to my application. In short, I am not sure how to automatically pass a windows message automatically into WndProc to be overrode.